# Error en Microsoft SQL Server: "Los datos de cadena o binarios se truncarían"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con muchos campos. Según está [página](https://codigosql.top/sql-server/los-datos-de-cadena-o-binarios-se-truncarian/#:%7E:text=Para%20solucionar%20el%20error%20los,columna%20para%20evitar%20ese%20error.) el error se debe a que en uno de los campos estoy intentando insertar un dato que supera la longitud máxima establecida en la tabla para este campo. Para resolverlo se recomienda identificar el campo (o los campos) y corregir el tamaño permitido en la tabla. Pero debido a que la tabla en cuestión es muy grande llevo más de 12 horas intentando encontrar el campo culpable.

---

**El método que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:**

*Hice un `SELECT` en el que especifico campo por campo un `CAST` igual al de la tabla y lanzo la query por cada campo hasta recibir el mismo error que obtengo al usar el `INSERT` en todos los campos.*

**¿Existe una forma eficaz de identificar el campo responsable?**

Comment: ¿Haces `INSERT-SELECT`?

Comment: Claro, mi `INSERT` cuenta con un `SELECT`, pero eso no me ayuda a identificar los campos que generan el error.

Comment: En realidad acabo de encontrar los cuatro campos implicados que ocasionaban el problema, pero fue una pesadilla. Sigo deseando saber si existe una forma más eficaz de identificar los campos sin tener que descartarlos uno a uno manualmente.

Comment: Podrías usar `sp_columns`, uno por cada tabla. Ordena el resultado por nombre de columna y compara los tamaños igualando por nombre de columna, la diferencia debería saltar a la vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Existe una forma eficaz de identificar el campo responsable?

Si pensamos en una forma lo suficientemente flexible para resolver el problema en las múltiples formas de obtener un recordset, es decir desde un a tabla, o de múltiples, con columnas combinadas, o consultas dinámicas o SPs o Funciones, o a través de linked servers. La respuesta es NO.

Puedo sí, de cualquier forma, proponerte algunas metodologías posibles:

#### Prueba y error

Es la mecánica más flexible y más tediosa, tienes una consulta que retorna 10 columnas, y que dispara un error de este tipo. El procedimiento es "divide y vencerás", es decir repites la consulta pero solo insertando las primeras 5 columnas, si obtienes un error, repites el procedimiento achicando a la mitad las columnas, sino obtuviste un error pruebas con las mitad de las siguiente 5 columnas y así hasta aislar la columna del problema.

#### `Select * into`

Algunas formas de obtener un recordset permiten realizar un `select * into <tabla temporal>`, lo cual básicamente implica la creación dinámica de la tabla. Por ejemplo, supongamos esta consulta que seguramente da un error:

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE (
    name VARCHAR(40)
)

INSERT INTO @Tabla (name)
SELECT  name
    FROM master.sys.objects so
```

Obviamente podrías tener muchas más columnas, la idea, de cualquier forma, es insertar en una tabla creada automáticamente esta consulta, y entonces sí, verificar las longitudes. Tomamos la consulta original y la insertamos directamente en una temporal de sesión:

```
SELECT  name
    INTO #TMP
    FROM master.sys.objects so
```

Y ahora, simplemente, verificamos las longitudes máximas de cada columna:

```
SELECT  MAX(LEN(name))
    FROM #TMP
```

Y obviamente habrá que comparar estos valores máximos con los de la tabla final dónde queremos insertar los datos.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, en mi caso ya tenía una tabla de proveniencia, así que con `SELECT  MAX( LEN( Campo ) ) FROM Tabla` pude resolver mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo así:

Yo utilicé para este ejemplo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Esta query muestra para cada columna de la tabla destino el nombre, el tipo de datos, la longitud máxima, la precision, la escala, si puede ser nulo, etc (podés agregar otra información que en este caso omití). nombre_tabla_destino sería el nombre de tu tabla destino (donde vas a insertar los datos). Te va a servir para comparar luego con la información que obtengas de la tabla origen.

```
SELECT 
 C.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
       TYPE_NAME(C.USER_TYPE_ID) AS DATA_TYPE,
       C.IS_NULLABLE,
       C.MAX_LENGTH,
       C.PRECISION,
       C.SCALE
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C
JOIN SYS.TYPES T
     ON C.USER_TYPE_ID=T.USER_TYPE_ID
WHERE C.OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('nombre_tabla');
```

Salida:

| OLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE | MAX_LENGTH | PRECISION | SCALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PersonID | int | True | 4 | 10 | 0 |
| LastName | varchar | True | 255 | 0 | 0 |
| FirstName | varchar | True | 255 | 0 | 0 |
| Address | varchar | True | 255 | 0 | 0 |
| City | varchar | True | 255 | 0 | 0 |

Luego a partir de la query anterior podés generar automaticamente queries sobre la tabla origen.

Por ejemplo: con está query armas una query (o podés armar varias) la cual vas a ejecutar después. En este caso cada columna varchar de la tabla se corresponde con una fila, y también muestra la longitud de la cadena mas larga en esa columna.

```
SELECT 
  'SELECT ''' + C.NAME + ''' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(' + C.NAME + ')) AS maxLength FROM Persons UNION ' AS query
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C
JOIN SYS.TYPES T
     ON C.USER_TYPE_ID=T.USER_TYPE_ID
WHERE C.OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('Persons') AND TYPE_NAME(C.USER_TYPE_ID) = 'varchar';
```

La salida de esta query es:

| query |
| --- |
| SELECT 'LastName' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(LastName)) AS maxLength FROM Persons UNION |
| SELECT 'FirstName' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(FirstName)) AS maxLength FROM Persons UNION |
| SELECT 'Address' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(Address)) AS maxLength FROM Persons UNION |
| SELECT 'City' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(City)) AS maxLength FROM Persons UNION |

Entonces copias todas esas filas como una unica query, reemplazas el último UNION por un punto y coma, y la ejecutas:

```
SELECT 'LastName' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(LastName)) AS maxLength FROM Persons UNION 
SELECT 'FirstName' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(FirstName)) AS maxLength FROM Persons UNION 
SELECT 'Address' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(Address)) AS maxLength FROM Persons UNION 
SELECT 'City' AS nombreColumna, MAX(LEN(City)) AS maxLength FROM Persons;
```

El resultado sería este:

| nombreColumna | maxLength |
| --- | --- |
| Address | 132 |
| City | 52 |
| FirstName | 72 |
| LastName | 85 |

Te retorna para cada campo varchar de la tabla origen la longitud de la cadena mas larga que contiene.

Así podés generar diferentes combinaciones según lo que necesites.