# Cantidad de actividades por cada mes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla llamada ejecutivos, el cual almacena el Id y el nombre de ejecutivos:

```
| Id | Nombre  |
|----|---------|
| 1  | Pablo   |
| 2  | Jose    |
| 3  | Enrique |
| 4  | Alfonso |
```

Y una tabla de actividades, la cual tiene el Id del ejecutivo, la fecha realizada y el nombre de la actividad:

```
| Id_ejecutivo | Fecha_actividad | Actividad                  |
|--------------|-----------------|----------------------------|
| 1            | 15-07-2020      | Reunion Cliente            |
| 2            | 03-11-2020      | Listado de materiales      |
| 2            | 21-03-2020      | Llamar a cliente           |
| 3            | 06-04-2020      | Actualizacion de contrato  |
| 4            | 18-07-2020      | Llamar a cliente           |
| 1            | 11-10-2020      | Ofertas                    |
| 2            | 30-03-2020      | Actualizacion de contactos |
| 3            | 16-12-2020      | Visita a sede central      |
| 4            | 05-09-2020      | Reunion cliente            |
```

El asunto es que debo generar una query, que muestre el nombre del ejecutivo, y hacia la derecha todos los meses del año 2020 y la suma total de las actividades hechas por cada mes. Ej:

```
| Ejecutivo | Enero | Febrero | Marzo | Abril | Mayo | Junio | Julio | Agosto | Septiembre | Octubre | Noviembre | Diciembre |
|-----------|-------|---------|-------|-------|------|-------|-------|--------|------------|---------|-----------|-----------|
| Pablo     | 11    | 0       | 0     | 10    | 6    | 13    | 22    | 37     | 20         | 25      | 17        | 32        |
| Jose      | 22    | 9       | 7     | 0     | 11   | 12    | 15    | 20     | 3          | 5       | 10        | 16        |
| Enrique   | 37    | 25      | 23    | 27    | 30   | 17    | 31    | 20     | 10         | 19      | 26        | 25        |
```

El asunto es para ser sinceros, no he podido lograr una query que muestre los resultados asi, si he podido listarlos en formato **Cantidad - Mes** hacia abajo, pero no como me lo piden.

Espero me puedan ayudar, es primera vez que me enfrento a este problema.

Editado: Esto llevo en la query que muestra a los usuarios mas el mes y la cantidad:

```
SELECT
    t2.Nombre,
    MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) as mes,
    COUNT(*) as Cantidad
FROM actividades as t1
LEFT JOIN ejecutivos as t2
    ON t1.Id_ejecutivo = t2.Id
WHERE YEAR(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 2020
GROUP BY MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad), t2.Nombre
```

El drama con esta query, es que no muestra en el formato que antes mencione mas arriba

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas intentado

Comment: @BetaM, edite con la query que utilizaba antes. De momento no llevo nada extra, ya que no logro dar con los resultados en el formato que necesito.

Comment: Mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/444396/21). Un saludo.

Comment: Estimado, ese ejemplo esta bastante bueno y lo agradezco mucho, me servira para aprender mas en sql server (No tenia idea de pivot), pero en este casoi voy a ocupar la query que publico @nachospiu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra solución puede ser:

```
SELECT
    t2.Nombre AS Ejecutivo,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Enero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Marzo,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Abril,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mayo,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Junio,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Julio,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Agosto,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Septiembre,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ocutbre,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Noviembre,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Diciembre

FROM actividades as t1
LEFT JOIN ejecutivos as t2 ON t1.Id_ejecutivo = t2.Id
WHERE YEAR(t1.Fecha_actividad) = 2020
GROUP BY t2.Nombre
```

La expresión CASE la implementan la mayoría de las bases de datos relaciones (y las que he probado lo implementan bastante parecido), en cambio la clausa pivot (o pivot table) solo algunas. En ambos casos tenés que especificar todas las columnas de la query final "a mano" (no lo hace automático).

Comment: Si bien es cierto lo que mencionas sobre la clausula `pivot`, la consulta es específica para SQL-server, donde si existe dicha cláusula.

Comment: Por otro lado, al agrupar por mes y nombre del ejecutivo, esto va a devolver hasta 12 registros por cada ejecutivo, y lo que el AP persigue es tener un solo registro por cada ejecutivo. ¿Por qué es necesario agrupar por mes?

Comment: Se que la pregunta está tagueada para SQL-server, pero por ahí alguien que usa otra base de datos (que no soporta la clausula pivot o lo hace de otra manera) tiene el mismo problema y puede encontrar solución, por eso agregué el comentario. Si, tenés razón, solo agrupá por nombre (copié la query de @Oriel y no modifiqué el GROUP BY), ahí lo corregí.

Comment: Quién puso los tags de la pregunta fué el AP, no yo.

Comment: @jachguate me parece importante brindar diferentes soluciones a un mismo problema, creo que ese es el sentido de está página.

Comment: Con esto último estoy totalmente de acuerdo. Lamento si mis comentarios anteriores han hecho pensar que me opongo a que haya variedad de respuestas. En realidad, estaba haciendo ver que el argumento para presentar la respuesta no me parece el mejor, nada más que eso, además que, en su momento, era incorrecta, cosa que ya se corrigió. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias @nachospiu, a las finales opte por tu opcion y funciono bien.

Comment: De nada @Oriel! Me alegra que te haya sido útil.

Comment: Disculpa @nachospiu moleste nuevamente, pero habra una forma en la cual se pueda mostrar la misma informacion con tu query, pero hasta el mes actual? O sea, por ejemplo ahora hasta abril, proximo mes hasta mayo y asi?

Comment: Hola @Oriel, no es molestia. Si entiendo bien, vos lo que querés es variar dinamicamente la cantidad de columnas que retorna la query, la solución que se me ocurre es generar la query dinamicamente (con algún lenguaje, que podría ser sql) en función de la fecha actual. O sea me refiero a armar la query dinamicamente, y agregar CASEs en función del mes de la fecha actual.

Comment: Este es un ejemplo de una [query dinámica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/440530/218615), primero ejecutas una query para armarla, y luego ejecutas la query que retorna. Aunque es mas facil hacerlo con algún lenguaje de programación.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo, a las finales termine optando por hacerlo dinamicamente por lenguaje de programacion, agregando los SUM(Case) segun los meses que me piden y fue mas facil.

Comment: De nada @Oriel! Me alegro lo hayas podido resolver.