# ¿Cómo hacer un resumen de contador de registros por mes (pivote)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Tengo una tabla que tiene registros de encabezados de facturas de clientes, llamada `Factura`, con información como esta:

```
IdCliente  | Fecha      | NumeroFactura | y otros campos
-------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2021-01-01 |        201345 | ...
2          | 2021-01-01 |        201346 | ...
1          | 2021-01-17 |        203148 | ...
1          | 2021-01-31 |        207941 | ...
2          | 2021-02-11 |        209147 | ...
1          | 2021-02-28 |        211249 | ...
```

Y deseo construir una consulta que me resuma la cantidad de facturas por cliente por cada mes del año, para el 2021, con una estructura como esta:

```
IdCliente  | Ene  | Feb  | Mar  | Abr  | May  | Jun  | Jul  | Ago  | Sep  | Oct  | Nov  | Dic  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          |   3  |   1  |   7  |  12  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |
2          |   1  |   4  |  11  |  21  |   7  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |
3          |   0  |   0  |  17  |  14  |   9  |   8  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |
etc.
```

Si se pudiera incluir el nombre del cliente, mejor.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esa consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograr el objetivo con una sentencia SQL más estándar, sin utilizar la cláusula `pivot` como sugiero en esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/444396/21)

Para lograrlo, aplicaremos dos *trucos*:

- Para obtener el valor de la columna correspondiente a cade mes, hacemos una sumatoria, en lugar de un contador.
- Sumamos el resultado de una sentencia `case` que devuelve 1 para los registros que son del mes de la columna y 0 en cualquier otro caso.

De esta forma, *simulamos* el contador, y obtenemos exactamente el resultado que buscamos.

Finalmente agrupamos por idCliente:

```
select   idCliente
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Ene
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Feb
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Mar
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Abr
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) May
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) Jun
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) Jul
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) Ago
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) Sep
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) Oct
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) Nov
       , sum(case when month(fecha) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) Dic
  from Factura
 where year(fecha) = 2021
 group by idCliente;
```

Si queremos obtener el nombre del cliente, simplemente hacemos el *join* a la tabla Cliente y ajustamos la consulta para traer el nombre del cliente y agrupar por dicho campo, por ejemplo:

```
select   Cliente.Nombre
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Ene
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Feb
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Mar
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Abr
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) May
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) Jun
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) Jul
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) Ago
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) Sep
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) Oct
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) Nov
       , sum(case when month(Factura.Fecha) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) Dic
  from Factura
       inner join Cliente on Cliente.idCliente = Factura.idCliente
 where year(Factura.Fecha) = 2021
 group by Cliente.Nombre;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte de la cláusula [`pivot`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) para realizar un resumen de los datos y a la vez *rotar* la información para mostrarla en columnas, de la manera que deseas.

En casos como este, el código vale más que mil palabras, la consulta es:

```
select idCliente, [1] Ene, [2] Feb, [3] Mar, [4] Abr, [5] May, [6] Jun, [7] Jul, [8] Ago, [9] Sep, [10] Oct, [11] Nov, [12] Dic
  from (select idCliente, month(fecha) mes
          from Factura
         where year(fecha) = 2021
       ) as q1
 pivot (count(mes)
          for mes in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
       ) as pvt
```

Las partes que requieren explicación, en mi opinión, son:

- Al `pivot` se le da una consulta como origen de datos, en esta consulta aprovecho para extraer el mes de cada factura de manera numérica y filtrar los registros del año que nos interesan:

  ```
  select idCliente, month(fecha) mes
    from Factura
   where year(fecha) = 2021
  ```
- En el `pivot` utilizo la función `count()` para *resumir* la información de la manera que nos interesa. Acá también podríamos utilizar otras funciones que agregan información, como `sum()` o `avg()` para producir *informes* con totales de ventas o venta promedio, por decir un par de ejemplos.
- En el select principal voy asignando alias a las columnas que, para entonces, ya aparecen con el *número de mes* como título, así, `1` es `Ene`, `2` es `Feb`, etc.
- Para las columnas de los meses, me veo obligado a encerrar su nombre entre `[]`, ya que no son identificadores válidos, así la columna `1` puedo referenciarla como `[1]` sin error.

Si quieres incluir el nombre del cliente, mi sugerencia es hacer un `join` después de realizar el `pivot`, para ello puedes valerte de un CTE, por ejemplo:

```
with
Resumen as (
select idCliente, [1] Ene, [2] Feb, [3] Mar, [4] Abr, [5] May, [6] Jun, [7] Jul, [8] Ago, [9] Sep, [10] Oct, [11] Nov, [12] Dic
  from (select idCliente, month(fecha) mes
          from Factura
         where year(fecha) = 2021
       ) as q1
 pivot (count(mes)
          for mes in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
       ) as pvt
)
select Cliente.Nombre, Resumen.Ene, Resumen.Feb... etc.
  from Resumen
       inner join Cliente on Cliente.idCliente = Resumen.idCliente;
```